# AsyncFileUpload control

Tags: asp.net, asyncfileupload

Regarding the AsyncFileUpload control in .net, the control will execute the file upload once i select a file. In my concern is, is it possible to disable the upload once i select a file so that i could process the upload asynchronously with a submit button.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I beat my head on this for a while, so for whoever might be interested.

My first thought was to disable the file input underneath the control.

I was able to disable the control but unfortunately, it stopped working. When the server fired AsyncFileUpload_UploadComplete the input was diabled so there wasn't a file to read.

```
<script>
function disableFileUpload(on) {
    if (on) {
        $('#ajax-file-input input:file').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(#ajax-file-input 'input:file').attr('disabled', false);
    }
}
function AsyncFileUpload_CheckExtension(sender, args) {
    disableFileUpload(true);
    return true;
}
function AsyncFileUpload_OnClientUploadComplete(sender, args) {
    disableFileUpload(false);
    var data = eval('(' + args.d + ')');
    for (var key in data) {
        var obj = data[key];
        for (var prop in obj) {
            console.log(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
        }
    }
    doThingsWith(data);
}
</script>
<div id="ajax-file-input">
<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" 
                    OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload_UploadComplete"
                    OnClientUploadStarted="AsyncFileUpload_CheckExtension" 
                    OnClientUploadComplete="AsyncFileUpload_OnClientUploadComplete" 
                    runat="server" />
</div>
```

I ended up positioning a semi-transparent png on top of the control and showing and hiding it to make the control innaccesible.

Hope this helps.

```
function disableFileUpload(on) {
    if (on) {
        $("#file-disabled").show();
    } else {
        $("#file-disabled").hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that the only event exposed by `AsyncFileUpload` is the `UploadComplete` event and `UploadError`. There aren't events specifically that expose functionality to manually initiate the upload. Perhaps some trick in JavaScript could do it but I have not seen such a workaround before.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is No. I've had similar asyncupload issues just like those ones. My advice is to stay away from him if you need to control upload with a button, add and remove selected files (you will probably need this later on) and use some javascript manipulation.

Search for the SWFUpload, is a flash component that can be integrated with .NET with ease. It offers multiple javascript options and events. :D

Check the following links:

[Official site](http://www.swfupload.org)

[Demonstration](http://www.swfupload.org/documentation/demonstration)

Comment: I have just gone through the SWFUpload and i found out that uploaded files will be stored at where the upload.aspx is located. So my question is, how to store the file into database?

Comment: You can use the FileBytes property and save it to the DB. When you set up SWF and choose a URL to post to, use the filebytes (a byte array) to save to a database